# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categories')

Tags: reactjs, undefined, categories, mern

[enUncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categories')ter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLl3r.png)

```
const Category = () => {  
const renderCategories = (categories) => {
    let myCategories = [];
    for (let category of categories) {
      myCategories.push(
        <li key={category.title}>
          {category.title}
      
        </li>
      );
    }
    return categories;
  };
```

```
return (
    <Fragment>
 <ul>{renderCategories(category.categories)}</ul>
</Fragment>
)};
```

Comment: your `category` object does not have a `categories` property

Comment: Yes, Agree with Ahmed, Please provide more code.